# How to evaluate these parameter

Tags: probability, gre-exam

[image]

This is a gre question so the Figure is not drawn to scale. So we can not guess that $BAD$ is right triangle. 
Can I evaluate these answer without knowing the right angle from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question directly states that ABCD is a rectangle, so you can safely assume that angles BAD, ADC, CDB and CBA are all right angles. It is impossible to find any of the answers otherwise.

Comment: Ohh sorry my bad I forgot. It is now okay.